# How to do this contour integral with two branch cuts?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)}}$$ where $z_1$ and $z_4$ is in the contour but $z_2$ and $z_3$ is out of the contour. And the branch cut can be taken between $z_1$ and $z_4$ and between $z_2$ and $z_3$ in order to avoid the intersection of the contour and branch cuts.

PS: If there is no analytical expression for the above integral, how about this $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(z-1+\delta)(z-1-\delta)(z+1+\delta)(z+1-\delta)}}$$ where $\delta>0$ and $\delta\rightarrow 0$

Comment: If
$$f(z) = \frac 1 {z
 \sqrt {1 - \frac {z_1} z} \sqrt {1 - \frac z {z_2}}
 \sqrt {1 - \frac z {z_3}} \sqrt {1 - \frac {z_4} z}},$$
then, for all complex $z_i$ s.t. $|z_{1, 4}| < 1$ and $|z_{2, 3}| > 1$,
$$\int_{|z| = 1} f(z) \, dz =
\frac {4 i}
 {\sqrt {1 - \frac {z_1} {z_3}} \sqrt {1 - \frac {z_4} {z_2}}}
 K {\left( \frac {(z_1 - z_4) (z_2 - z_3)} {(z_1 - z_3) (z_2 - z_4)} \right)},$$
where $\sqrt z$ is the principal value of the square root and $K(m)$ is the analytic continuation from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$.

Comment: Would you please explain a little bit more about the procedures to derive this result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And K(m) is the "Complete elliptic integral of the first kind" right?

Comment: Correct, and $m$ is the parameter (not the elliptic modulus). We start with the case $z_2 < z_1 < z_4 < z_3$. The substitution
$$z = \frac {z_1 (z_4 - z_2) - z_2 (z_4 - z_1) u^2}
 {z_4 - z_2 - (z_4 - z_1) u^2}$$
reduces $\int_{z_1}^{z_4}$ to the standard form. The formula for complex $z_i$ works because both sides are analytic functions of $z_i$. $m > 1$ can happen only if $z_i$ lie on a generalized circle in the order $(z_{1 \lor 4}, z_{2 \lor 3}, z_{1 \lor 4}, z_{2 \lor 3})$, which is impossible.